# Search nested object via property for nth level childrens

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, javascript-objects

I have below data and want to search all nested object via given property and would return matching object with all property(name, guid, children, customProperties),

need to have something simmilar below.

```
searchMe(data, {name :'Commercial Banking', guid:'46754a70-a59b-4b1e-bbb8-3f4ecb5aa484'});
```

or just

```
searchMe(data, {name :'Commercial Banking'});
```

and should return below.

```
{"name":"Commercial Banking","children":[{"name":"Beautiful Page","title":"Beautiful Page","guid":"985d6b61-cda5-4ec2-b012-4655542ffdf4","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}},{"name":"Beautiful Page 1","title":"Beautiful Page 1","guid":"7af89020-8317-401e-b0b0-2e2ef071c62d","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}},{"name":"Credit and Risk Learning Solutions","title":"Credit and Risk Learning Solutions","guid":"cde723d9-3dcf-4e3e-84dc-392f15556c64","customProperties":{}},{"name":"FLAGSHIP PROGRAMMES","title":"FLAGSHIP PROGRAMMES","guid":"64950405-7b44-464e-b07a-5adc882d1388","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Just Another Title","title":"Just Another Title","guid":"730e133e-e286-4739-82eb-0cfeab954b79","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}},{"name":"Just Page","title":"Just Page","guid":"329d6e98-4953-4f14-af33-6fdf0eef4472","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}},{"name":"New Programme","title":"New Programme","guid":"afb8fb63-814e-450b-9944-73a5b6433fca","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}},{"name":"New to Commercial Banking","title":"New to Commercial Banking","guid":"064bef6c-5db0-49e0-9224-fc9925a8e7fd","customProperties":{}},{"name":"PRODUCTS AND SERVICES","title":"PRODUCTS AND SERVICES","guid":"03d516dc-588b-4f91-9500-cc12008e4e0e","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Commercial Banking","guid":"46754a70-a59b-4b1e-bbb8-3f4ecb5aa484","customProperties":{}}
```

```js
'{"children":[{"name":"HOME","children":[],"title":"HOME","guid":"164d6e25-e3e2-4dc1-b39e-ca46af6e8e1c","customProperties":{"_nav_image":"https://team.global.samplecompany/sites/SAMPLECOMPANYUni/SiteAssets/Branding/images/hsbc_university_icon_small.png","_nav_image_css":"width:40px;margin-top:13px","_theme_file":"/sites/hsbcuni/Style%20Library/samplecompany/css/samplecompany-home.css"}},{"name":"BUSINESS AND ROLE SPECIFIC","children":[{"name":"Global Businesses","children":[{"name":"Commercial Banking","children":[{"name":"Beautiful Page","children":[{"name":"Sample","children":[],"title":"Sample","guid":"506dce63-8cce-483b-a797-693aee974073","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}}],"title":"Beautiful Page","guid":"985d6b61-cda5-4ec2-b012-4655542ffdf4","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}},{"name":"Beautiful Page 1","children":[{"name":"Sub Beautiful Page","children":[],"title":"Sub Beautiful Page","guid":"4df7c891-c98d-44a5-83f1-f97ca65e5ff1","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}}],"title":"Beautiful Page 1","guid":"7af89020-8317-401e-b0b0-2e2ef071c62d","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}},{"name":"Credit and Risk Learning Solutions","children":[{"name":"Beautiful Page","children":[{"name":"Sub Page","children":[],"title":"Sub Page","guid":"a7aa4b90-269c-45f0-8b92-b047596899ee","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}}],"title":"Beautiful Page","guid":"5591c792-a027-401c-83af-50989f77a33c","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}},{"name":"Delete Me","children":[{"name":"Delete","children":[{"name":"Another Page","children":[],"title":"Another Page","guid":"ba46e999-7237-4807-886a-366eb045c475","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}}],"title":"Delete","guid":"d07a4c26-3ecd-4b60-824a-21d6ea4e3af1","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}}],"title":"Delete Me","guid":"59c5f423-f4dc-4a9d-b6b2-76d1f333f8d7","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}},{"name":"sample page","children":[],"title":"sample page","guid":"b102e74b-5e72-4e62-a9b2-972c0faf58a1","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}}],"title":"Credit and Risk Learning Solutions","guid":"cde723d9-3dcf-4e3e-84dc-392f15556c64","customProperties":{}},{"name":"FLAGSHIP PROGRAMMES","children":[{"name":"Sample-1-%$%$%-new","children":[],"title":"Sample-1-%$%$%-new","guid":"28535678-b411-4b5b-abc3-3ea3cb7dccca","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}}],"title":"FLAGSHIP PROGRAMMES","guid":"64950405-7b44-464e-b07a-5adc882d1388","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Just Another Title","children":[],"title":"Just Another Title","guid":"730e133e-e286-4739-82eb-0cfeab954b79","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}},{"name":"Just Page","children":[],"title":"Just Page","guid":"329d6e98-4953-4f14-af33-6fdf0eef4472","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}},{"name":"New Programme","children":[{"name":"Sample","children":[],"title":"Sample","guid":"ffa20ae7-9805-4670-86fa-fa7385e4c462","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}}],"title":"New Programme","guid":"afb8fb63-814e-450b-9944-73a5b6433fca","customProperties":{"_Sys_Nav_IsNavigationTermSet":"True"}},{"name":"New to Commercial Banking","children":[],"title":"New to Commercial Banking","guid":"064bef6c-5db0-49e0-9224-fc9925a8e7fd","customProperties":{}},{"name":"PRODUCTS AND SERVICES","children":[],"title":"PRODUCTS AND SERVICES","guid":"03d516dc-588b-4f91-9500-cc12008e4e0e","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Commercial Banking","guid":"46754a70-a59b-4b1e-bbb8-3f4ecb5aa484","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Retail Banking And Wealth Management","children":[{"name":"Retail Product Academy","children":[],"title":"Retail Product Academy","guid":"e390e70d-26f4-4b9d-9497-9ba41c44b373","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Role Base Learning","children":[{"name":"Branch Manager","children":[],"title":"Branch Manager","guid":"6de4c263-379f-47d9-a3e5-825e19487b95","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Role Base Learning","guid":"565dd01b-5366-4ce9-8109-bc03644b81c0","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Retail Banking And Wealth Management","guid":"677b7bc1-f429-4f2b-9347-463ac1aa89f7","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Global Banking And Markets","children":[{"name":"In Focus","children":[],"title":"In Focus","guid":"28161752-9998-4833-8a62-d8732fd8725a","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Leadership Development","children":[],"title":"Leadership Development","guid":"1ceda6e2-f294-4e0c-9f1d-b65bc3b57158","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Learning Resources","children":[],"title":"Learning Resources","guid":"1658e6cb-a31a-4dd0-8899-3ce9906e7576","customProperties":{}},{"name":"MY GBM CAREER","children":[],"title":"MY GBM CAREER","guid":"526c7620-cb5e-4faf-9b9a-aaad171328cf","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Role Based Learning","children":[],"title":"Role Based Learning","guid":"00756cbc-292c-4d01-a51f-acc9cfab0e58","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Sample","children":[],"title":"Sample","guid":"0272e1b8-ae7f-4493-b478-653933e39a00","customProperties":{}},{"name":"sample-1","children":[{"name":"role base learning","children":[],"title":"role base learning","guid":"cf1ddf3e-3c4f-48d6-8021-94ef68c07cd0","customProperties":{}}],"title":"sample-1","guid":"4d3dea87-4c1b-49a3-bfca-a0ce145745b6","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Global Banking And Markets","guid":"75a87cea-e4d2-4cf2-8fc3-1c5db778f008","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Global Private Banking","children":[],"title":"Global Private Banking","guid":"a6e927f9-43b0-4051-b003-77b12bfbeae6","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Global Businesses","guid":"8448c34a-d453-4c71-b869-dfccb4f55289","customProperties":{}},{"name":"HOST","children":[{"name":"COO Office","children":[{"name":"CDM","children":[],"title":"CDM","guid":"45a00e34-8c79-437c-8ef5-917012ea55c6","customProperties":{}}],"title":"COO Office","guid":"f90fd832-05f2-4c1f-93ae-3cdf08098bf1","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Corporate Real Estate","children":[{"name":"CDM","children":[],"title":"CDM","guid":"6275f846-f58b-4544-9ecc-4d5eb2076e08","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Corporate Real Estate","guid":"bb486ce9-3edd-4797-9390-59f64cf87961","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Global Operations","children":[{"name":"CDM","children":[],"title":"CDM","guid":"67f3dc2e-6428-4ba5-b3c9-402b9992dd0f","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Global Operations","guid":"0cd1f7d5-a658-4ca6-801c-7bf1ff4c42d6","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Global Procurement","children":[{"name":"CDM","children":[],"title":"CDM","guid":"220866bd-3e3d-4968-a1f2-a4a48b72ae03","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Global Procurement","guid":"04e3ccdd-6c44-49a7-8abf-25706090f719","customProperties":{}},{"name":"SAMPLECOMPANY Technology","children":[{"name":"CDM","children":[],"title":"CDM","guid":"8d58fe18-f0a9-4940-8b7f-d9fa7daf4ba7","customProperties":{}}],"title":"SAMPLECOMPANY Technology","guid":"7d743c4b-1fbe-4fec-b4fc-ad5001fa6a77","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Transformation","children":[{"name":"CDM","children":[],"title":"CDM","guid":"c5cdea2b-13dc-49c6-be51-b1eebcb3f4c3","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Transformation","guid":"4612d483-71f7-4435-a4c2-001b14dc3d1b","customProperties":{}}],"title":"HOST","guid":"152bb895-21ff-49cc-bf63-5056b8641d5f","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Global Functions","children":[{"name":"Communications Coming 2018","children":[],"title":"Communications Coming 2018","guid":"c59c219b-9f8f-41a5-aebf-7cfc5608e254","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Finance","children":[],"title":"Finance","guid":"13bd480b-1e3f-4c1d-8260-81c65324b904","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Financial Crime Risk","children":[],"title":"Financial Crime Risk","guid":"8f11b831-0994-4b07-b1d9-b6eee6b675c2","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Human Resources","children":[],"title":"Human Resources","guid":"5c6cb723-2ad4-4548-927b-b52b653a119c","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Internal Audit Coming 2018","children":[],"title":"Internal Audit Coming 2018","guid":"3fd99ec2-13bb-4ad5-8249-557c4777dc1c","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Legal","children":[],"title":"Legal","guid":"559280c1-6414-4420-88b5-0127b7422edc","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Marketing","children":[],"title":"Marketing","guid":"6854a064-492b-43db-9e3b-154bf904d13d","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Risk","children":[],"title":"Risk","guid":"cd5894b6-d23c-4f44-8508-6b139e3660c3","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Strategy And Planning","children":[],"title":"Strategy And Planning","guid":"16f41d0e-7a99-45e8-9c7d-35799251de19","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Global Functions","guid":"29af5ab4-7551-4b42-a0bf-96fe9f34da1d","customProperties":{}}],"title":"BUSINESS AND ROLE SPECIFIC","guid":"723790ab-02a6-434a-8eb7-685b3db2a44c","customProperties":{"_nav_image":"https://team.global.samplecompany/sites/SAMPLECOMPANYUni/SiteAssets/Branding/images/business_role_specific_icon_small.png","_theme_file":"/sites/hsbcuni/Style%20Library/samplecompany/css/samplecompany-business-role-specific.css"}},{"name":"LEADERSHIP","children":[{"name":"Leadership","children":[{"name":"Leadership Overview","children":[],"title":"Leadership Overview","guid":"c74b77cd-709d-4dfa-bdb7-012025cb490b","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Leadership","guid":"deb39ad6-306f-4e06-9297-1c6292bfe29d","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Leading Others","children":[{"name":"Accelerated Development Programme","children":[],"title":"Accelerated Development Programme","guid":"c42d6bf3-b262-40d0-aa93-1d2d064ee4e6","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Coaching for Performance","children":[],"title":"Coaching for Performance","guid":"e70abce4-13b5-44f9-9574-e69735483d1e","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Hiring Essentials","children":[],"title":"Hiring Essentials","guid":"a4f0fa1c-b021-40d9-9e32-6f648d1c45f6","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Leadership Essentials","children":[],"title":"Leadership Essentials","guid":"05dd5478-2458-423e-9956-4a5df600c797","customProperties":{}},{"name":"People Management Essentials","children":[],"title":"People Management Essentials","guid":"246e6a9e-cbe8-4669-8f55-1e998900fb51","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Team Management Essentials","children":[],"title":"Team Management Essentials","guid":"61d645bb-e968-4205-9210-452096e42abc","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Leading Others","guid":"fbf47d62-5ec2-422b-9bd7-300c5ed25b3a","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Leading Self","children":[{"name":"Personal Leadership","children":[],"title":"Personal Leadership","guid":"a08633b4-ba5f-4a13-a5a5-db2cf28858f6","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Working Through Others","children":[],"title":"Working Through Others","guid":"d8e6891e-5dba-45e2-bc05-e714d9a76edd","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Leading Self","guid":"61966fe0-eac8-4ab5-8b0d-87175e98cc0e","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Leading a Business or Function","children":[{"name":"Accelerated Executive Programme","children":[],"title":"Accelerated Executive Programme","guid":"ea834c71-73f1-4d67-92ac-2b4f73bfcd8a","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Country Leadership","children":[],"title":"Country Leadership","guid":"d92093f1-2ea7-4d61-991a-532301301468","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Leading Businesses and Functions","children":[],"title":"Leading Businesses and Functions","guid":"a4e84bf7-c5d4-4a4c-bb6a-feebe4ae7a83","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Leading with Impact","children":[],"title":"Leading with Impact","guid":"07bafe58-926c-4473-9222-00fd8d03751c","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Leading a Business or Function","guid":"288d2fa6-43d3-4916-bb3f-89937ed9a7db","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Leading the Organisation","children":[{"name":"Executive Speaker Series","children":[],"title":"Executive Speaker Series","guid":"c44e9e6b-9477-4bd9-b71a-0cb58f92c2ef","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Leading with Impact","children":[],"title":"Leading with Impact","guid":"1c80b174-54b0-469c-8522-64a606308561","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Leading the Organisation","guid":"015117fb-49a9-4352-8cb8-13a9ea917337","customProperties":{}}],"title":"LEADERSHIP","guid":"77657356-75dc-4592-8a9a-3ab3b0371c67","customProperties":{"_nav_image":"https://team.global.samplecompany/sites/SAMPLECOMPANYUni/SiteAssets/Branding/images/leadership_icon_small.png","_theme_file":"/sites/hsbcuni/Style%20Library/samplecompany/css/samplecompany-leadership.css"}},{"name":"RISK MANAGEMENT","children":[{"name":"Building Financial","children":[],"title":"Building Financial","guid":"62d30ca6-4dc9-4ca9-a99b-73c0791e9ddf","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Global Mandatory Training","children":[],"title":"Global Mandatory Training","guid":"9b4122f6-706e-4ce5-a0dd-2b7083de50de","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Risk Programmes","children":[{"name":"Asset and Liability Committee Management Programme","children":[],"title":"Asset and Liability Committee Management Programme","guid":"6a92e14e-2254-4ac4-a3b6-ba6840711f93","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Risk Management Programme","children":[],"title":"Risk Management Programme","guid":"8cf363c5-c025-4c20-a347-544c82f78b85","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Risk Management for Leaders","children":[],"title":"Risk Management for Leaders","guid":"9fd80fb3-29bf-4545-b870-666780703169","customProperties":{}}],"title":"Risk Programmes","guid":"27ac7cc0-2b4f-484b-b513-c19467d1e56a","customProperties":{}}],"title":"RISK MANAGEMENT","guid":"07fb60b6-a17d-427b-808c-6f81e83b41e3","customProperties":{"_nav_image":"https://team.global.samplecompany/sites/SAMPLECOMPANYUni/SiteAssets/Branding/images/risk_management_icon_small.png","_theme_file":"/sites/hsbcuni/Style%20Library/samplecompany/css/samplecompany-riskmanagement.css"}},{"name":"Admin","children":[{"name":"brightcove","children":[],"title":"brightcove","guid":"7d9059bc-d05a-4742-b077-39471c510686","customProperties":{"_theme_file":"/sites/hsbcuni/Style%20Library/samplecompany/css/samplecompany-home.css"}},{"name":"demowidget","children":[],"title":"demowidget","guid":"c8e5f8fd-c5d8-4513-96f5-76bc96ca77a0","customProperties":{"_theme_file":"/sites/hsbcuni/Style%20Library/samplecompany/css/samplecompany-home.css"}},{"name":"editor","children":[],"title":"editor","guid":"9cbec22f-2254-4d2c-9947-f9f6f3411dc9","customProperties":{}},{"name":"html5demo","children":[],"title":"html5demo","guid":"d64eca8e-6238-418d-a63b-a63475e7daa3","customProperties":{"_theme_file":"/sites/hsbcuni/Style%20Library/samplecompany/css/samplecompany-home.css"}},{"name":"searchresults","children":[],"title":"searchresults","guid":"4b5a8fab-925e-44da-b83f-f2badb11bc8c","customProperties":{"_theme_file":"/sites/hsbcuni/Style%20Library/samplecompany/css/samplecompany-home.css"}}],"title":"Admin","guid":"2408d996-5911-48b0-82ad-80e6d330050e","customProperties":{"_nav_image":"https://team.global.samplecompany/sites/SAMPLECOMPANYUni/SiteAssets/Branding/images/hsbc_university_icon_small.png","_nav_image_css":"width:40px;margin-top:13px","_theme_file":"/sites/hsbcuni/Style%20Library/samplecompany/css/samplecompany-home.css"}},{"name":"STRATEGY AND PERFORMANCE","children":[{"name":"New to SAMPLECOMPANY","children":[{"name":"Discovery Global Induction","children":[],"title":"Discovery Global Induction","guid":"272d008a-7227-4bb9-ae23-7d23c7995f5a","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Executive Discovery","children":[],"title":"Executive Discovery","guid":"8ffb4efe-d54d-4f94-81fc-6dc82b79887d","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Innovation in the Digital Age","children":[],"title":"Innovation in the Digital Age","guid":"30796c3a-a587-46f1-a6fb-b5c54f6dcf0a","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Leaders as Teachers","children":[],"title":"Leaders as Teachers","guid":"e38efd2f-0df0-4c9c-aa4a-b45160e920e4","customProperties":{}},{"name":"Sustainability Leadership Programme","children":[],"title":"Sustainability Leadership Programme","guid":"c0082190-de90-4fb2-90f6-7e0f6212bb88","customProperties":{}}],"title":"New to SAMPLECOMPANY","guid":"ab38e64a-c0e5-4c0f-8326-dff5b13414ba","customProperties":{}}],"title":"STRATEGY AND PERFORMANCE","guid":"a8b93668-3196-4b70-9d40-5f8a85690f94","customProperties":{"_nav_image":"https://team.global.samplecompany/sites/SAMPLECOMPANYUni/SiteAssets/Branding/images/performance_culture_icon_small.png","_theme_file":"/sites/hsbcuni/Style%20Library/samplecompany/css/samplecompany-strategy-and-performance.css"}}]}';
```

and

Comment: @ChrisG, it does not do nested search and I could have n level childrens and need to search all

Comment: @rajesh can you please point me to duplicate thread?

Comment: @rrk can you please point me to duplicate thread?

Comment: @cerbrus can you please point me to duplicate thread?

Comment: below is ans thanks to @ChrisG who marked as duplicate without even reading post and comparing, function findChild(obj, condition) {
  if (Object.entries(condition).every(([k, v]) => obj[k] === v)) {
    return obj;
  }
  for (const child of obj.children || []) {
    const found = findChild(child, condition);
    // If found, then add this node to the ancestors of the result
    if (found) {
     found.children.forEach(function(child, idx) {
        delete found.children[idx].children;
      });
      var returnValue = found;
      return returnValue;
    }
  }
}